# NetworkX draw grid_2d_graph with nodelist value from file

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx

I am trying to draw grid_2d_graph with nodelist values from file.

```
list1 = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)] 
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=list1, node_color='b')
```

In the above statement, instead of manually setting the nodelist, I want to read the nodelist from a file. That file will contain the list of nodes that should be colored blue.

I tried reading from the file and putting the retrieved value in the nodelist, but its giving error Node '(0,1)' has no position because may be I am storing it as a string.

Can anyone please suggest how to read nodelist values from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach for storing the node colors as node attributes and saving them in a GraphML format file.  Then you can read that file and unpack the nodes and attributes into lists to pass to nx.draw() (or nx.draw_networkx_nodes())

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
# create graph 
G=nx.Graph()
# with nodes that have attribute "color"
G.add_nodes_from('abc',color='r')
G.add_nodes_from('de',color='b')
G.add_edges_from([('a','b'),('b','d'),('c','e'),('b','e')])
# save/load in graphml format
nx.write_graphml(G,'color_test.graphml')
H=nx.read_graphml('color_test.graphml')
# get nodes and colors as lists from graph attributes
nodes,colors=zip(*nx.get_node_attributes(H,'color').items())
nx.draw(H,nodelist=nodes,node_color=colors)
plt.show()
```